Solving the integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos^2 x\ dx}{\cos^2 x + 4\sin^2 x}$
My textbook has the following problem: $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos^2 x\ dx}{\cos^2 x + 4\sin^2 x}$.  This website solves the problem in a very convoluted way and I was wondering if there's an easier approach to this.
I divided throughout by $\cos^2 x$ to get:
$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dx}{1 + 4\tan^2 x}$, but to no avail.

Whats the name of that textbook though ?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410671/evaluate-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-cos2x-dx-cos2x4-sin2x?noredirect=1

Let's finish your proof:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1+4\tan^2(x)} dx$$
Let $u=\tan(x)$, hence the differential element $du=\sec^2(x) dx$ and the bounds overall become:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+4u^2} \frac{du}{\sec^2(x)} $$
Yet $\sec^2(x)=u^2+1$ by our previous subsitution. Thus we obtain:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+4u^2} \frac{du}{1+u^2} $$
By partial fractions, we obtain:
$$\frac{-1}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{u^2+1} du + \frac{4}{3} \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{4u^2+1} du $$
$$=-\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}+u^2} du$$
$$=-\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{2}{3}\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

$$\int^{π/2}_0 \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)+4\sin^2(x)}dx$$
We can multiply the numerator and denominator by $\sec^4(x)$ and get
$$\int^{π/2}_0 \frac{\sec^2(x)}{\sec^2(x)+4\sec^2(x)\tan^2(x)}dx$$
We write $\sec^2(x)$ as $\tan^2(x)+1$
$$\int^{π/2}_0 \frac{\sec^2(x)}{1+5\tan^2(x)+4\tan^4(x)}dx$$
Substitute $u=\tan(x)$ and $du=\sec^2(x)dx$ . This gives a new lower bound $u_1=\tan(0)=0$ and upper bound $u_2=\tan(t)$ as $t \to \frac{π}{2}$ so $u_2=\infty$
$$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{1}{4u^4+5u^2+1}du=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{4}{3(4u^2+1)}-\frac{1}{3(u^2+1)}du$$
Factoring out the constants and integrating term by term we get
$$\frac{4}{3}\int^{\infty}_0\frac{1}{4u^2+1}du-\frac{1}{3}\int^{\infty}_0\frac{1}{u^2+1}du$$
For the integrand $\frac{1}{4u^2+1}$ ,substitute $s=2u$ and $ds=2du$ this doesn't change the bounds and we get
$$\frac{2}{3}\int^{\infty}_0\frac{1}{s^2+1}ds-\frac{1}{3}\int^{\infty}_0\frac{1}{u^2+1}du$$
Now we just evaluate the antiderivatives at the limits and subtract
$$\lim_{b \to \infty}\frac{2}{3}\tan^{-1}(s)|_0^{b}-\frac{1}{3}\lim_{b \to \infty}\tan^{-1}(u)|^b_0\\=\frac{π}{3}-\frac{π}{6}=\frac{π}{6}$$

Let's finish your proof :
$I = \int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}} \frac {1}{1 + 4\tan^2x} \rm{d}x\\
= \int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}} \frac {sec^2x - tan^2x}{1 + 4\tan^2x} \rm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}} \frac {sec^2x}{1 + 4tan^2x} \rm{d}x - \int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}} \frac {tan^2x}{1 + 4tan^2x} \rm{d}x\\ = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{1 + 4t^2} \rm{d}t - \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}\frac {4tan^2x + 1 - 1}{1 + 4\tan^2x} \rm{d}x \\= \frac{π}{4} - \frac{π}{8} + \frac{1}{4}I\implies \frac{3}{4}I = \frac{π}{4} - \frac{π}{8}\implies I = \frac{π}{6}$.
